# meteor collection.find().fetch(), running on the client in iron router returns an empty array

Tags: meteor, meteor-collections

Here's my code in a file named route.js on the client:

```
data: function () {
var sHash = this.params.sHash,
    cursor = Sites.find({siteHash:sHash}),
    obj = cursor;
    console.log("cursorData = ", obj);
}
```

When I run this, cursorData returns:
L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}

The cursorData obj contains the data I am looking for, and I could get at with a forEach, but I want to access it as an array.

So, this is my code using fetch().

```
data: function () {
    var sHash = this.params.sHash,
    cursor = Sites.find({siteHash:sHash}),
    obj = cursor.fetch();
    console.log("cursorData = ", obj);
}
```

Now cursorData returns:
cursorData =  []

I wasn't using pub/sub but all the solutions to this problem suggested it, so I tried and it made no difference.
I have already programmed around this, but being new and trying to learn the nuances of Meteor, I would like to understand why I can't get this to work when I see it being used everywhere else.

Comment: Are you waiting on the subscription to `Sites`?

Comment: Ensure the subscription is complete before running the cursor. You can use iron routers waitOn: function. E.g.    waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe("name-of-subscription"); },